# Durandal child router updating bindings only once

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

The router that I have created successfully builds a navigation model, but it's missing to update some bindings that need to be updated each time a page is loaded within that `childRouter` (`app.pageTitle`, `app.pageDescription`).

Is there some way how to map these updates into Durandal's lifecycle, something like `activate` event?

```
define([ 'durandal/app', 'plugins/router', 'knockout', 'app' ], function(app, router, ko, app) {

    console.log("content start");

    var childRouter = router.createChildRouter().makeRelative({
        moduleId : 'app/content/pages',
        fromParent : true
    }).map([ {
        route : [ '', 'grid' ],
        moduleId : 'grid/index'
    }, {
        route : 'details/:id',
        moduleId : 'details/index'
    }, {
        route : 'details/tabs/base',
        moduleId : 'details/tabs/base'
    } ]).buildNavigationModel();

    console.log("cms title start");
    app.pageTitle(app.i18n('app:modules.content.title'));
    app.pageDescription(app.i18n('app:modules.content.subtitle'));
    console.log("cms title stop");

    return {
        router : childRouter
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution that works would be adding `activate` function and returning it. Durandal will then call it everytime a page from the `childRouter` navigation model is requested.

```
define([ 'durandal/app', 'plugins/router', 'knockout', 'app' ], function(app, router, ko, app) {

    console.log("content start");

    var childRouter = router.createChildRouter().makeRelative({
        moduleId : 'app/content/pages',
        fromParent : true
    }).map([ {
        route : [ '', 'grid' ],
        moduleId : 'grid/index'
    }, {
        route : 'details/:id',
        moduleId : 'details/index'
    }, {
        route : 'details/tabs/base',
        moduleId : 'details/tabs/base'
    } ]).buildNavigationModel();

    function activate() {
        console.log("cms title start");
        app.pageTitle(app.i18n('app:modules.content.title'));
        app.pageDescription(app.i18n('app:modules.content.subtitle'));
        console.log("cms title stop");
    }        

    return {
        activate : activate,
        router : childRouter
    };
});
```